# How to override rake database tasks in rails 4

Tags: oracle11g, rails-activerecord, jruby, jrubyonrails, ruby-on-rails-4.2

I have a rails 4.2.1 project on the jRuby platform connected to oracle with the following gem dependency:

```
gem 'activerecord-oracle_enhanced-adapter', git: "git@github.com:rsim/oracle-enhanced.git", branch: "rails42"
```

But when I run rake tasks like rake db:migrate, it invokes the default activerecord rake task instead of the ones defined in this gem. How do I make rails execute rake tasks from this gem instead of the default ActiveRecord tasks

Answer (score 0):

need to use this:

```
require 'active_record/connection_adapters/oracle_enhanced/database_tasks'
```

instead of rails 3.2 style:

```
load 'active_record/connection_adapters/oracle_enhanced.rake'
```